# if...else (with exists()) in R function returning "unused argument" error

Tags: r, function, if-statement

I am trying to learn to make different variations of basic functions on my own. However, despite my test statement defining "x" within `if`, the returning results did not execute the `else` correctly. I googled various tutorial sites such as DataCamp and Khan. The syntax, from what I can see, is correct. Was hoping someone out there may see differently and could explain why?

```
p <- function() {
  if (!exists("x")) {
    x <- "there is no number"
  } else {
    x <- "what do you want to add?"
  }
  x
}
```

Below is the screen shot of my console:
[function with returning Error "Error in p(4) : unused argument (4)"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk2mf.jpg)

Various attempts:

- I tried removing the "x" framing in my exists() but when I try to run `p()` , I get a `Error in exists(x) : object 'x' not found` and with `p(4)`, it returned a `Error in p(4) : unused argument (4)`
- I adjusted `p <- function(x)` as well, but then received for `p()` an `Error in exists(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default`  With `p(4)`, an `Error in exists(x) : invalid first argument`
- Removing the ! negation in `exists()` yielded a `p()` return of `"what do you want to add?"` and with `p(4)` an `Error in p(4) : unused argument (4)` again.

---

Should I *not* use `exists()` within the test statement after all? Did I make this unnecessarily complicated on myself?

Anna

Comment: You can't pass an argument to a function of 0-arity (i.e. one that does not take any arguments)

Comment: Hello Bill, To clarify, I should define my ``p <- function(x)`` in the beginning? I tried and both ``p()`` and ``p(4)`` returned the "there is no number" from my ``else`` statement. Sorry, am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Bill, Thank you! I'll redo my code and give this a try. I wanted to master the basic syntax before daring to move on to more complicated functions. Much appreciated you taking the time and effort to guide me!

Comment: If you're just writing a wrapper around the base R exists() function, just do: myExists <- function(x) ifelse(!exists(x), "there is no number", "what do you want to add?") . Is that your intent?

Comment: Sorry, I realized I did not directly answer your question. My intention for the function was if ``p()`` was run, it would return ``"there is no number"`` However, if something was in the argument like ``p(4)``, the function was to return a ``"what do you want to add?"``

The ``ifelse(!exists("x')`` returned "what do you want to add?" with both ``p()`` and ``p(4)`` When I debugging, it returned the error was within ``exists()`` but I did ``exists(x)`` and I kept getting a "invalid first argument" so I did ``("x")``  What the?

Comment: You can test for optional arguments using the missing() function

Answer (score 0):

So you definitely need to have an argument in your function.  Plus I don't think you have to do all that assigning within the if/else statements.  I think this gets what you're looking for, but not sure:

```
p <- function(some_object) {
  if (!exists(some_object)) {
    "there is no number"
  } else
    "what do you want to add?"
}

x <- 1 + 1

p("x")
```

Comment: see last comment above for her variadic function request

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a collaboration of both Bill and Ben's answers worked!

I gave up on using `exists()` and tabled it to master on another day. Meantime, with both codes merged, I got this:

```
p <- function(x) {
  if (missing(x)) {
    "there is no number"
  } else
    "what do you want to add?"
}
```

`missing()` was definitely a far friendlier function to use. I achieved the results I aimed for. `p()` returned a "there is no number" and `p(4)` returned a "what do you want to add?" At last!

Thank you both for helping me tackling what I *thought* was going to be a simple function. Clearly not! I'm going to tackle `missing()` and `exists()` ad nauseum and master this.

Much gratitude for the advice! I'm going to post the answer here in case another encounters the same snag.

Gratefully Yours,
Anna